# .htaccess убирание .php не работает

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, linux

Добрый день. Перенёс сайт с домашнего сервера на VPS. Перестало воспринимать ссылки без .php.
Мой .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.php$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]*)$ events.php?id=$1
```

Не работает только эта строчка:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Логи:

```
[Sat Dec 20 04:02:06 2014] [error] [client 93.74.206.142] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/home (None could be negotiated).
```

Что делать - не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А с какой целью стоит / перед $1?

Comment: Это следы моих экспериментов. Я пробовал всё, что мог, чтобы решить свою  проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! \.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! /$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: 500 internal. в логах: /var/www/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Comment: Вероятно, стоит убрать пробелы после !